# Error Message : HMS Convertor Failed to execute the engine analysis task

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am using Apple M1 Max and getting Failed to execute the engine analysis task while using HMS Convertor tool.

Comment: Could you please share the log obtained when the issues occurred ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the supported environment in the link below. Issue could be with Mac OS version

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881

Supported Operating Systems
Android Studio and  tool is tested in Windows 10, macOS 10.12/10.13/10.14/10.15, and Ubuntu 14.04/16.04/18.04.

Supported Android Studio UI Themes
Windows: Darcula/IntelliJ
macOS: Darcula/Default